# Do $n$ polynomials in $n$ variables have a finite number of solutions outside of a set of measure 0 for the choice of coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, abstract-algebra, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider $n$ polynomials in $n$ variables, of the same class, homogenous quadratics etc. if that makes it easier, where we choose the coefficients randomly with a probability distribution absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.

Can we say that with probability 1, or equivalently outside of a set of Lebesgue measure for the choice of constants, that the system of polynomials has a finite number of solutions?

Comment: You are probably looking for something like [Thom's transversality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_theorem). Additionally, there is the Bezout bound on the number of isolated roots, there is Kroneckers elimination theory, there is Gröbner bases and how to interpret the set of leading monomials to determine the (maximal) dimension of the solution set and to count the number of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider some polynomial system $F(x)=0$ in $n$ variables with $n$ equations. Then construct the function
$$
G(c,x)=F(x)+c
$$
As the Jacobian of $G$ has full rank, $\frac{\partial G}{\partial c}=I$, $G$ is transversal to $\{0\}$. Thus for almost all parameter vectors $c$, $G_c=F+c$ is also transversal to $\{0\}$ which means that its Jacobian has full rank in every root. Thus all roots are isolated, and by the Bezout bound, the set of roots is finite.